# Find document pairs in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection of documents with following structure:

```
id: ObjectId
name: String
placeSeen: String
dateTimeSeen: Date
```

I need to find pairs of documents by matching `name` representing "trips". The goal is to see the travel times from one point to another. Person can go from any place to any place they want.

e.g. (using sample data below): I need to have result that would make it easier to get info like:
"John went from A1 to B1 and it took him 2 minutes. John went from B1 to C1 and it took him 2 minutes. John went from C1 to A1 and it took him 3 min"

Currently I'm thinking of doing it by iterating complete collection; for each document's `name` field I could do search for first matching `name` with different `placeSeen` sorted by `dateTimeSeen` ascending. It would kinda work, but it doesn't seem really efficient - many rows to iterate.

What would be a better approach?

Sample data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e933a186983c6f2978e8a1"), 
    "name" : "John", 
    "placeSeen" : "A1", 
    "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:25:41.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e9354486983c6f2978e8a9"), 
    "name" : "John", 
    "placeSeen" : "B1", 
    "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:27:41.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e9355186983c6f2978e8ab"), 
    "name" : "John", 
    "placeSeen" : "C1", 
    "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:29:41.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e9355186983c6f2978e8ac"), 
    "name" : "John", 
    "placeSeen" : "A1", 
    "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:32:41.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e9358186983c6f2978e8ad"), 
    "name" : "Sue", 
    "placeSeen" : "B1", 
    "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:21:41.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e9358c86983c6f2978e8af"), 
    "name" : "Sue", 
    "placeSeen" : "A1", 
    "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:24:41.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e9359686983c6f2978e8b1"), 
    "name" : "Sue", 
    "placeSeen" : "C1", 
    "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:29:41.000+0000")
}
```

Comment: can places repeat for the same person? or is the sequence of places they go to unique?

Comment: Person can go to any place from any place: So John can go to B1 and then to C1 and then to A1 and to C1 back etc. (added that to question also)

Comment: I added correct answer based on your previous sample data but I added another place for Sue.  I just updated to add the point for John that you added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation.  The key is to figure out how to pair the dates/places, grouping them by each person is the easy part.

I used your sample data, but I added another data point for "Sue" which was a place she had already visited before - this is to show that it can work with repeated visits as long as times are correctly examined.

```
db.went.find({},{_id:0})
{ "name" : "John", "placeSeen" : "A1", "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:25:41Z") }
{ "name" : "John", "placeSeen" : "B1", "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:27:41Z") }
{ "name" : "John", "placeSeen" : "C1", "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:29:41Z") }
{ "name" : "Sue", "placeSeen" : "B1", "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:21:41Z") }
{ "name" : "Sue", "placeSeen" : "A1", "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:24:41Z") }
{ "name" : "Sue", "placeSeen" : "C1", "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:29:41Z") }
{ "name" : "Sue", "placeSeen" : "B1", "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:35:00Z") }
{ "name" : "John", "placeSeen" : "A1", "dateTimeSeen" : ISODate("2016-03-16T10:32:41Z") }
```

Here's the aggregation:

```
db.went.aggregate( [
    /* we want time to be sorted for each person in the next step */
    {$sort:{name:1,dateTimeSeen:1}}, 
    /* group each person's places and times into a single document */
    {$group:{ _id:"$name", places:{$push:{place:"$placeSeen",time:"$dateTimeSeen"}}}},
    /* this duplicates the "places" arrays into identical field "trips" */
    {$project:{trips:"$places",places:1}},
    /* unwind one of the arrays */
    {$unwind:"$places"},
    /* $filter keeps only elements of "trips" that are "later" than "place", 
     * then we only want the first element of remaining ones */ 
    {$project:{ "places":1, 
                "to": {$arrayElemAt:[ 
                   {$filter {
                      input:"$trips",
                      as:"trip",
                      cond:{$and:[
                          {$ne:["$places.place","$$trip.place"], 
                          {$lt:["$places.time","$$trip.time"]}
                      ]}
                   }},
                   0
                ]}
    }},
    /* if "to" is null then it's the last point (no destination, remove) */
    {$match:{to:{$ne:null}}}, 
    /* format the "trip" output and calculate duration */
    {$project:{ _id:0, 
                name:"$_id",
                trip:{$concat:["$places.place","-","$to.place"]},
                durationSeconds:{$divide:[{$subtract:["$to.time","$places.time"]},1000]}
    }}
] )
```

The output:

```
{ "name" : "Sue", "trip" : "B1-A1", "durationSeconds" : 180 }
{ "name" : "Sue", "trip" : "A1-C1", "durationSeconds" : 300 }
{ "name" : "Sue", "trip" : "C1-B1", "durationSeconds" : 319 }
{ "name" : "John", "trip" : "A1-B1", "durationSeconds" : 120 }
{ "name" : "John", "trip" : "B1-C1", "durationSeconds" : 120 }
{ "name" : "John", "trip" : "C1-A1", "durationSeconds" : 180 }
```

You must be using 3.2.x or later - I'm using several aggregation expressions that were introduced in 3.2.0.